# Trying to install fbprophet package on ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, facebook-prophet

While trying to install fbprophet, the installation gets stuck at this part

Building wheels for collected packages: prophet
Building wheel for prophet (setup.py) ... |
pystan and ephem have been installed.
Os-ubuntu 20.04

Comment: did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

You need to install `pystan` before `fbprophet`.

[Installation instruction:](https://github.com/facebook/prophet#installation-in-python)

> The default dependency that Prophet has is pystan. PyStan has its own installation instructions. Install pystan with pip before using pip to install prophet.

```
python3 -m pip install pystan==2.19.1.1
sudo apt install python3-dev
python3 -m pip install prophet
```

Comment: still isnt working after installing pystan

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me but FIRST I installed: pip install lunarcalendar

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 21.04, I followed these instructions

https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/b75844e07c3b09bf3bc383c9d43241c554dd251b/Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.7-stretch

RUN apt-get -y install libc-dev

RUN pip install pip==19.1.1

COPY python/requirements.txt .

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
...
```

I installed the python dependencies

```
sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev \
libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm \
libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libxml2-dev libxmlsec1-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev
```

I installed python 3.7.10 with [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv).

I installed the [requirements](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/facebook/prophet/b75844e07c3b09bf3bc383c9d43241c554dd251b/python/requirements.txt)

```
Cython>=0.22
cmdstanpy==0.9.68
pystan~=2.19.1.1
numpy>=1.15.4
pandas>=1.0.4
matplotlib>=2.0.0
LunarCalendar>=0.0.9
convertdate>=2.1.2
holidays>=0.10.2
setuptools-git>=1.2
python-dateutil>=2.8.0
tqdm>=4.36.1
```

And I installed prophet

```
pip install prophet
```

### Other option

build the docker image from this [docker-compose.yaml](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/blob/b75844e07c3b09bf3bc383c9d43241c554dd251b/docker-compose.yml)

```
docker-compose build package
```

With that, you can use the built image.

Answer (score 0):

This should work in Ubuntu: After making sure you have the right python version.
Update apt and install following libraries.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3-dev python3-pip python3-venv
```

use python3 -m pip to install pystan and prophet

```
python3 -m pip install pystan 
python3 -m pip install prophet
```

Answer (score 0):

i did use conda and worked for me

```
conda install gcc_linux-64 gxx_linux-64 -c anaconda
conda install pystan -c conda-forge
conda install --yes \
    -c conda-forge fbprophet
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an update

I recently faced this issue on AWS EC2 running t2.micro with Ubuntu 20.

Some great guy bought us prebuilt wheels for prophet, here's the [link](https://pypi.org/project/prophet-prebuilt/)

Answer (score 0):

Pystan2 is no longer maintained and possibly the source of the issue.

In my case, I installed prophet locally from

https://github.com/facebook/prophet

Answer (score 0):

fbprophet is not supported anymore, I used instead
https://pypi.org/project/prophet/

and `pip install prophet`

Did work fine and old fbprophet code was running good.
I have Ubuntu 23.04 and python 3.11

Terveisin, Markus